# Dart: Type error when overrding generic function in abstract class

Tags: generics, dart, overriding, abstract

In Dart/ flutter I have the following classes:

```
abstract class Base {
   V foo<V, T>(T arg);
}

class Concrete implements Base {
   @override
   TypeA foo<TypeA, TypeB>(TypeB arg) {
       //... do something and return TypeA variable x
       return x;
   }
}
```

TypeA and TypeB are user defined types. However, I get the error message: <The value of type TypeB can't be returned from method 'foo' because it has a return type of TypeB>. Wired! Could you help me to understand what is going on here. What I try to get to is a general API function foo() where the input and output type can be defined flexibly by implemented classes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `TypeA` and `TypeB` here are *not* user-defined types. They are type variables which happen to have the same name as a user defined type.
Each call to `Concrete.foo` would need to pass type arguments, and the body needs to work for *any* type arguments (that's what being "generic" means, it works on generally for any type).

If you try to return something of the user-defined type `TypeA` from `Concrete.foo`, you get an error because it does not have the type of the type variable `TypeA` ... for *any* type that can be passed as a type argument.

My guess is that what you want is a generic class:

```dart
abstract class Base<V, T> {
   V foo(T arg);
}

class Concrete implements Base<TypeA, TypeB> {
   @override
   TypeA foo(TypeB arg) {
       //... do something and return TypeA variable x
       return x;
   }
}
```

which parameterizes the *interface* with the actual `TypeA` and `TypeB`.